# My Jar application(myapplication.jar + Mysql connector) doesnt work on other computer

Tags: java, jdbc

Guy i developt a simple GUI application to access mySQL database program, i created a jar file, everthings works great on my computer , my application could access database greatly, but the problem is when i run this myapplication.jar on others computers, my GUI (application) showed up but can't access the database.

my questions are:

1. did i have to copy "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 6.0\data\MyDatabase\" files inside my applications folder ?

i've create a manifest file to link myapplication.jar to mysql-connector-java-5.1.17.jar , plus i put mysql-connector-java-5.1.17.jar in same folder, but it seem my application can't access the database on others computers .

Comment: First rule of programming: read the error message.

Comment: If I were you, I would become more acquainted with intermediate Java programming and other databases such as DB4) before creating business-critical applications. Also please edit your post to make the wording coherent and not panicky.

Comment: thank you, yes i know i'm very panick now...,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you need to know is how MySQL works. It is a client and a server, which is probably local in this case.

When you bring the application to the other computer, you'll want to install a MySQL server on that machine as well and set it up with the same tables and data(via MySQL backup and restore).

I would become more acquainted with intermediate Java programming and other databases such as DB4) *before* creating business-critical applications.

Comment: thank you again, i know i still a junior , but how about game ??,when we copy a game which use a database(let'say mysql server) to our computer , we don't need to install mysql server on our computer right??, all we know is just clicking the game and play...

Comment: @febri23 Because it likely doesn't *use* MySQL. Likely SQLite or something embedded.

Comment: okay hexafraction i got what you mean now, i've understand about the portability of SQLite (which is portable)..,my eyes have just opened right now.., So all i need is just to install mysql server on the other computers set it up with the same tables and data(via MySQL backup and restore). right ??

Comment: @febri23 Yes, that is the idea behind this. Best of luck with the program! Also please checkmark this answer if it heleped/.

Comment: thank you very much hexafraction, this is my first official software ever, beautiful simple software with hugh functionality to maintain all stuffs n workers data in a shop, but because this project is for my family shop so i didn't even ask a penny to my mom , XD.. ,i've just migrated to SQLite that i never use before , thx God SQlite's queries almost exactly same with others RDBMS.., thx for introduce me to this SQLite and made me understand their difference with mySQL. GBU bro.

Comment: done !!!!! with SQLite..

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect to sql through that computer. You can either copy your sql on that or you can point it the sql on you computer using the ip path.

Comment: Copy MySQL tables as files? Not a good idea.

Comment: I am talking about the SQL server. Either copy or repoint to existing (if on the same network)

Comment: thank you very much for your response guys, you mean i copy the database files to another computers , just copy them ?? without installing mysql server on that machines??

Comment: In business applications, we usually host database at a different machine and the application connects to database via network. For development purposes, we maintain both the database as well as application on single machine. Thats what you did. Now if the other machine is going to use that application it must have some SQL server to connect to.

Comment: i got it , got it.. thanks GV ,so now i've to comeback to my house and install SQL server on that machine...thank you guys again

Comment: thank you very much GV, this is my first official software ever, beautiful simple software with hugh functionality to maintain all stuffs n workers data in a shop, but because this project is for my family shop so i didn't even ask a penny to my mom , XD.. ,i've just migrated to SQLite that i never use before , thx God SQlite's queries almost exactly same with others RDBMS.., thx for introduce me to this SQLite and made me understand their difference with mySQL. GBU bro.

Comment: done !!!! with SQLite..

Comment: Your welcome. Keep coding :-)